# Did I play this hand correctly?

Tags: texas-hold-em, hand-history

So I got JTs on the button and everyone folds to me, there's only one player left in the BB.

I raise 1 BB and he calls.

The flop comes 7 10 Q.

I bet 1/2 of the pot since I have a blocking T and I want to look like I got a Q.

He raises and at this moment I think he got a QA or similar.

Fourth street is a J, and I bet 3/4 of the pot. He raises and I go all-in.

He shows QT, and I lost.

Did I play this hand correctly?

Comment: Can you verify that you were on the button, or the Small Blind? It's not clear. Also, how much did villain raise on the flop?

Answer (score 1):

I would say, no - you did not play well. you do not have the strongest pair, and of course he could have two pairs even worse, three of a kind. You are kind of playing a bluff, so consider that u know player also is olaying to bluff could make sense, but no other way around